# Programmatically adding content to tinymce

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to use javascript to add text input to a tinyMCE editor,
I can append the text visually using :

```
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent('&nbsp; words and stuff ');
```

have also tried

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent('&nbsp;');
```

Which will allow me to see the text specified above no problem,  however when i go to save its almost as if the javascript didnt actually append the text where it should have or something,  my save is the original text without the text appended above, does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue i was having was, I would add text into tinymce with the javascript line

```
function AddNotes(NoteS) { 
    tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false ,NoteS);
}
```

And for some reason, I needed to insert into the tinymce TWO TIMES for it to work.

So what I did to compensate was added the information that I want to add, and then I throw in a paragraph element which creates a new line under what I just added. I could have added a space, or whatever I want but I chose to add a new line as seen below:

```
function AddNotes(NoteS) { 
    tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, NoteS); 
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<p></p>');
}
```